# Regex help matching 5 lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm looking for some help from a regex guru, here's what I want to be able to match and remove using ruby/rails:

```
-----Original Message-----
From: STATIC on behalf of STATIC
Sent: Thu 11/25/2010 11:17 AM
To: Random, Random
Subject: Random replied to the comment
```

is it possible with regex to match these 5 lines with one Regex? Here's what I've been trying, without luck:

```
gsub(/-----Original Message-----/n.* From.*/n Sent.*/n To.*/n Subject.*/, '')
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reverse the slashes for the newlines and remove the extra space after each newline.

```
-----Original Message-----\n.*From.*\nSent.*\nTo.*\nSubject.*
```

http://rubular.com/r/z9NwUT7FWJ